# SQL запрос на поиск самого большого числа после текущего на PHP

Tags: php, sql, числа

Данные:

Например есть переменная `$data['rating']` с значением 999.

Задача:

Как составить правильно `sql` запрос в базу данных чтоб найти ближайшее самое большое число но меньшее текущему?

Прошу помощи в реализации.

Comment: если найти в принципе то `select {$data['rating']} - 1`, если выбрать из таблицы, то `select rating from xxx where rating < ? order desc limit 1`

Answer (score 0):

Вроде как-то так:

```
SELECT rating
FROM table
WHERE rating < YOUR_VALUE
ORDER BY rating DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(rating)
FROM table
WHERE rating < 999
```